# [JavaFX][FXML] Scrollpane filled by titlepanes. TitlePane filled by TilePane. (Changing container size due to changing element inside)

Tags: javafx, fxml

i've got following problems.

1. How, in FXML, put for ex. 3 TitlePanes into ScrollPane, in such way, that when i open all 3 TitlePanes, the vertical scroll will appear, but when i have for ex. 1 open it disappear? (fit ScrollPane height to it's dynamicaly changing content)
2. How, in FXML, put TilePane into TitlePane, that TitlePane will fit to it content? For ex. i put 4 Buttons into TilePane. At begining it's 2x2. When i reduce width, it change into 4x1, TilePane heigth grow, but TitlePane doesnt grow with it, and not all Buttons are visible. How to connect TilePane size with its container TitlePane size?

I'll be appriciate for any help.

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Comment: i thought that it's both connected with similar problem, that container didn't grow with its childrens. Only container and children were different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using FXML, make sure that you do not set the preferred height of the controls you want to resize, they should be set to COMPUTED.  With this set, a collapsed TitledPane will only take up the size of it's title.